# Continuous real action on affine functions over a Choquet simplex

Tags: real-analysis, ordered-groups, choquet-theory

Let $K$ be a metrizable Choquet simplex. We define $A=\operatorname{Aff}(K,\mathbb{R})$ as the set of real-valued affine continuous functions. This has both the structure of a real Banach space as well as a simple (uncountable) dimension group when equipped with the strict ordering.
Let us consider a point-norm continuous action $\alpha: \mathbb{R}\curvearrowright A$ by linear order-isomorphisms. (I do *not* assume $\alpha$ preserves the constant functions)

**Question 1 (not so specific):** Is there any known description how such actions $\alpha$ look like in terms of $K$ and possibly some extra data?

**Question 2 (specific):** Let $\tau\in\partial_e K$ be an element of the extremal boundary and $a\in A$ strictly positive. Does there exist some parameter $p>0$ such that $\{ p^{-t}\alpha_t(a)(\tau) \mid t\in\mathbb R \}$ is precompact inside $(0,\infty)$?

**Some motivation:** I don't have a good intuition for Question 1, but the only obvious examples I can come up with are first starting from an action induced from an affine continuous action $\mathbb{R}\curvearrowright K$, and then possibly rescaling them with exponential functions. But one has, at least in principle, some freedom to vary the scaling parameter over different extremal points. To illustrate this in a toy example, one can take $K=[0,1]$, in which case $A=\mathbb{R}^2$, and for any pair of distinct parameters $p_1>p_2>0$ one can define an action via $\alpha_t(x_1,x_2)=(p_1^tx_1,p_2^tx_2)$. This toy example also shows why Question 2 only makes sense for extremal $\tau$: Take for a moment $\tau=\frac12$, which induces the evaluation map on $A$ via $(x_1,x_2)(\tau)=\frac12(x_1+x_2)$. The above set depending on $p$ will have $\infty$ in its closure if $p<p_1$ (take $t\to\infty$) or if $p\geq p_1$ (take $t\to-\infty$), hence always. If $\tau$ is one of the two extremal points, however, then the answer to Question 2 is trivial.

Although the first question is likely to be difficult, a positive answer to the second question would represent a kind of weak assertion that extremal elements of $K$ must follow some kind of almost-exponential path along the orbit of a continuous action $\alpha$ as above.